Having an issue with a teleporting function on Roblox
The code is:
local function Teleport(TeleportPos)
  for i, Players in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers)) do
    Players.Character:FindFirstChild(“HumanoidRootPart”).CFrame = TeleportPosition
   end
end

The code is a function to teleport all players in the game to a certain part
The problem is that whenever I run the function in the code by doing Teleport(ForestSpawn1.CFrame), nothing happens at all and I have no idea what to do.

That's because your function has the parameter TeleportPos and your code uses TeleportPosition when setting the Player position.
Below I corrected the code to use the proper parameter name TeleportPos instead of TeleportPosition.
local function Teleport(TeleportPos)
  for i, Players in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers)) do
    Players.Character:FindFirstChild(“HumanoidRootPart”).CFrame = TeleportPos -- TeleportPos instead of TeleportPosition
   end
end


i think this is beceause you forgot to add a () to for i, Players in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers)) do, this script should work correctly with your game :
local function Teleport(TeleportPos)

for i, Players in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
  Players.Character:FindFirstChild(“HumanoidRootPart”).CFrame = TeleportPosition
  end
end

I hope this help :D

I tried that, but the code still didn't do anything, no errors in output just nothing
